# multiple ifelse statements and dplyr pipes, not recognizing 2nd object

Tags: r, dplyr

What I'm trying to do: take columns from one data frame, recode them using ifelse statements, and move them to a new data frame, all the while using dplyr and pipes to do it in one shot.

Issue: The code works fine for the with just one column but I am running into problems once R encounters more than one column in same line of code. The second column is not recognized and R throws an error. I get the following error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: object 'var2_orig' not found.

Any thoughts on why this is? There may also be an easier way to this without using ifelse statements. I am open to suggestions on this front as well, but I am still curious about how to do this with ifelse and why the error with more than one column. Many thanks.

Sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)

# creating fake data set
df_orig <- data_frame(var1_orig = sample(1:3, 50, replace = T),
                  var2_orig = sample(-2:2, 50, replace = T))

# works for one var (recoding 3's as NA, 2's as 1, and 1's as 0):

df_new <- df_orig %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  transmute(var1_new = ifelse(var1_orig == 3, NA, ifelse(var1_orig == 
  2, 1, ifelse(var1_orig == 1, 0, var1_orig))))

# and works the other var (recoding negatives as NA, 1's and 2's as 1, and 
leaving 0's as 0's):

df_new <- df_orig %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  transmute(var2_new = ifelse(var2_orig < 0, NA, ifelse(var2_orig == 
  1 | var2_orig == 2, 1, 0)))

# but not together in same line of code (error: var2_orig not recognized):

df_new <- df_orig %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  transmute(var1_new = ifelse(var1_orig == 3, NA, ifelse(var1_orig == 
  2, 1, ifelse(var1_orig == 1, 0, var1_orig)))) %>%
  transmute(var2_new = ifelse(var2_orig < 0, NA, ifelse(var2_orig == 
  1 | var2_orig == 2, 1, 0)))
```

Comment: `transmute` drops variables that it doesn't create. Use `mutate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transmute will drop the variables, hence the error. You can use `mutate` to update the existing variables and then `rename_all` (If needed) to change their names,

```
df_orig %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(var1_orig = ifelse(var1_orig == 3, NA, ifelse(var1_orig == 2, 1,
                                                         ifelse(var1_orig == 1, 0, var1_orig))),
           var2_orig = ifelse(var2_orig < 0, NA, ifelse(var2_orig == 1 | var2_orig == 2, 1, 0))) %>%
    rename_all(funs(sub('_.*', '_new', .)))
```

Answer (score 5):

The dplyr's verb `transmute` keeps only the variables you create, and drop the original varabiles, so `var2_orig` is not present anymore for the second `transmute`.

You can either create the two variable in the same `transmute` call, use `mutate`, and then drop the original variable if not needed.

By the way, `case_when` would be useful here:

```
df_orig %>% 
  transmute(var1_new = case_when(var1_orig == 3 ~ NA_integer_,
                              var1_orig == 2 ~ 1L,
                              TRUE ~ var1_orig),
            var2_new = case_when(var2_orig < 0 ~ NA_integer_,
                              var2_orig %in% 1:2 ~ 1L,
                              TRUE ~ 0L)
  )
#> # A tibble: 50 x 2
#>    var1_new var2_new
#>       <int>    <int>
#>  1        1        1
#>  2        1        1
#>  3        1        0
#>  4       NA       NA
#>  5       NA        0
#>  6        1       NA
#>  7        1        1
#>  8        1        1
#>  9        1        1
#> 10        1        1
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

Comment: great, I have been considering moving into the case_when function, so that might be useful in the long run.